How do you set a header after Post and before Get in Axios ReactJS?
I am working with Axios and ReactJS and I am trying to set the authorization header  using the token received from the login Post to be used in the following Get. However, when I check the headers under network in the Chrome console, I can see that the header was not set before the Get was sent. I first tried promise chaining, but could not get the header to set. I rewrote the code using async/await for readability. Is this an issue with the order in which ReactJS handles the requests and functions?
const handleLoginSubmit = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(LOGIN_API_URL, {
                                        'email': email, 
                                        'password': password,}
                                    );
        console.log(response);
        
        //Set local storage token and axios authorization common header
        const token = response.data.key;
        localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;

        const response2 = await axios.get(USER_API_URL);
        setUsername(response2.data.display_name);   
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

Thank you!

Make an axios instance which takes headers from localStorage
import axios from 'axios';

const getDefaultHeaders = () => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  return token ? { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } : {};
};

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  headers: getDefaultHeaders()
});

export default axiosInstance;

And use this axiosInstance for your GET requests
Alternatively, You can also make axios interceptors and append the token to header from request interceptors
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    // Get the token from local storage
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

    // If a token exists in local storage, add it to the request headers
    if (token) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }

    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    // Handle request errors
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

However if you follow best practices, Your token should not be kept in localStorage
Your token should be a short lived access token which you can store in a httponly samesite cookie else it will be susceptible to Cross site scripting attack
